# Pool Rewards distribution via SmartContract

Tags: smart-contract, stake-pool

For the Pool I run I would like to setup a SmartContract which automatically claims the rewards and sends a certain percentage to each of three organisation I support.

Is such a thing possible with smart contracts?

Can a SmartContract claim rewards?
Or do I have to claim the rewards "manually" and then send them to the Smart Contract to to it's work ?

Comment: Is there a reason your "three organizations" can't just stake from their own wallets and manage their own rewards?

Comment: I wan't to support three organisations via the rewards the PoolOwner (me) earns. The idea is to establish an automatic way to donate the pool owner rewards. The Rewards of "regular" delegators are not touched by this.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to write an off-chain script to do this for you. There is no trust involve (you already have access to your own spending key); there is no need to get the network to validate your transfers. And you are going to need a script/off-chain worker anyway to trigger the smart contract to send funds.

Comment: Ok thnx for the clarification, I thought about offline code initially, but like the fact that a Smart contract has the distribution written in code. I guess the best solution is then be to claim the rewards manually and send them to a smart contract address. Kind of an hybrid approach.

Answer (score 1):

The funds from a smart contract can be delegated to a stake pool. So if you wanted to have all the staked funds live at the contract you could accomplish something similar to what you are proposing.

There isn't such thing as "automatically" for Plutus smart contracts. They are passive. That being said, it might still make sense for you to set it up in a way that anyone (usually you) could trigger the distribution of the rewards. Each of these transactions will cost a small fee of course.

Comment: Can you explain hat you mean by "smart pool" never heard that ?

Comment: Typo. Meant "stake pool." Woops. Fixed it.